# Synchronize local folder with FTP

Tags: ftp, directory, sublimetext, synchronize

I Am developing a web app and i need upload a lot files to ftp (html, css, js, folders, images etc...).

Someone know some application to synchronize my local folder with FTP?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed package control, you can install `ftpsync`

Here is how you use FTPSync: '[How to use FTPSync](https://github.com/NoxArt/SublimeText2-FTPSync#how-to-use)'

Comment: If you're using package control, you also can install it in Sublime Text 3